# Kernel build for CentOS 7: kernel-firmware not generated

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, redhat, rpmbuild

I'm in the process of rebuilding the Linux kernel for Cent OS 7 to select a different preemption level.

My steps follow:

- `sudo yum install rpm-build redhat-rpm-config asciidoc hmaccalc perl-ExtUtils-Embed pesign xmlto  audit-libs-devel binutils-devel elfutils-devel elfutils-libelf-devel ncurses-devel newt-devel numactl-devel pciutils-devel python-devel zlib-devel gcc patchutils bison make gcc redhat-rpm-config`
- `mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{BUILD,BUILDROOT,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}`
- `echo '%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild' > ~/.rpmmacros`
- `wget http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/updates/Source/SPackages/kernel-3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.src.rpm`
- `rpm -i kernel-3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.src.rpm`
- `cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS`
- `rpmbuild -bp --target=$(uname -m) kernel.spec`
- Kernel in `BUILD` configured and config file copied in `SOURCES`
- `` rpmbuild -bb --with firmware --without kabichk --without debug --without debug-info  --without doc --target=`uname -m` kernel.spec 2> build-err.log | tee build-out.log ``
- `rpmbuild -bb --with firmware --without kabichk --without debug --without debug-info  --without doc --target=noarch kernel.spec 2> build-err.log | tee build-out.log`

(`--without kabichk` is needed because the new preemption level somehow breaks the current ABI)

The problem is that the package `kernel-firmware` gets not generated.
Any idea of what is missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to *be* a kernel-firmware package in CentOS 7 at all. And a quick search through the [kernel spec file](https://git.centos.org/blob/rpms!kernel/0cf3a004b8711b7aa4b356e7d0441069f9affcd4/SPECS!kernel.spec) confirms that `kernel-firmware` doesn't appear anywhere in it.

There is a linux-firmware package though.

That package is built by the [linux-firmware specfile](https://git.centos.org/blob/!rpms!linux-firmware.git/0e857641c673d8b5c29d16fca0ae98c463596f9d/SPECS!linux-firmware.spec).